# D-Link DWL-650+ doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my old HP laptop
I tried to use D-Link DWL-650+ PCMI WiFi card
it does not work
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found an older post indicating that this chipset is not supported, but that you might be able to use a windows driver for the wifi card.  You can follow the path at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper